# Jupyter: How can you pretty-print many data frames from the code in one cell?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, pretty-print

When you run a function that returns a Pandas data frame in a Jupyter cell, it prints out this very aesthetic table.  When you give an explicit command to print, it looks much worse.  I have a list of data frames and I'd like to print each.  Is there a way to get the nice version of the print using a for-loop?

Comment: use `display(df)` instead of `print(df)`

Comment: @ALollz That worked, if you want to make it an answer I'll accept it or I can close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, using `display` instead of `print` does the job.